# convert ViewBag value into integer type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

my ViewBag.searchid may contain either int value or string. If it contain string value like "this is mvc" the how will I convert that value in integer ?

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SearchForEdit(string entryid)
        {
            ViewBag.searchid =entryid;            
            ViewBag.searchsong = entryid.ToString();
            ViewBag.searchalbum = entryid.ToString();
            return PartialView("SearchForEdit");
        }
```

entryid value will get from textbox from viewpage. user can insert either id or string type value

Comment: What integer value do you think "this is mvc" should be??

Comment: Your logic has some serious flaws...

Comment: How to determine my ViewBag value is either int or string ?

Comment: @abhay9455 do you expect `searchid`, `searchsong` and `searchalbum` to have different values? A `.ToString()` on a string value is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
      ViewBag.test = 13;
                if (ViewBag.test is string)
                { 
                  //This is string
                }
                else if (ViewBag.test is Int32)
                {
                   //this is integer
                }
```

since ViewBag always contain dynamic datatype, so you can verify type of data at runtime.

Comment: How to determine my ViewBag value is either int or string ?

Answer (score 1):

```
            object searchID = ...;
            int numberResult = -1;
            if (Int32.TryParse(searchID, numberResult))
            {
                //searchID is an int and stored in numberResult
            }
            else
            {
                //searchID is a string
                //..saerchID.ToString();
            }
```

You can't convert 'this is mvc' to an integer since its a string. The code above determines whether the searchID is convertible to a string or not.

Comment: How to determine my ViewBag value is either int or string ?

Comment: You can either use the way I posted or the way Aaron did it.